# How to compare multiple datetimes and display them in one view?

Tags: laravel, php-carbon

I'm using carbon to compare two dates, initially I used two static variables, one that was `$Hnow = now()` and the other `$Hlim = Carbon :: Create($year, $month, $day, $hourM, $minute, $second);`
which were compared as follows:

```
$intervalH = $Hnow-> diffInHours ($Hlim);
```

and well it works perfectly for me, but now I have to adapt it to a database, where I have several timestamps and that instead of having a static $ Hlim, I have many dates, which are the limit to present a work. How can I compare each of those dates in my table with the current date and orderly display those data? I understand that timestamps cannot be compared to carbon so I converted it first, but it doesn't show me any captured date.

Controller:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\pamatrixinf;
use App\Periodicity;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Alertnotification;
use Carbon\Carbon;
use DateTime;

use App\pawork;

class fen extends Controller
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('auth');

    }

    public function index()
    {
        $hour= 14;
        $minute= 0;
        $second=0;
        $year= date("Y");
        $month= date("m");
        $day=date("d");
        $hourM=date("H");
        $dayy= now();

        $dateli=pamatrixinf::select('pamatrixinf.dateen')
        ->where('pamatrixinf.read_at','=',0,'AND')
        ->where('codpaarea', '=', auth()->user()->codarea)
        ->get();
        $datelim= strtotime($dateli);
        $datedif=Carbon::Create($year,$month,$day,$hourM,$minute,$second);
        $dateend= $datedif->addHour();
        $intervalH= $dayy->diffInHours($datelim);
        $intervalM= $dayy->diffInMinutes($dateend);



        return view('fen.index', [

        'Works' => Periodicity::select('paperiodicity.descriptionp','pamatrixinf.description', 'pamatrixinf.codpar')
                ->join('pamatrixinf', 'pamatrixinf.cod_paperiodicity', '=', 'paperiodicity.cod')
                ->where('pamatrizinfoperio.read_at', '=', 0, 'AND')
                ->where('pamatrizinfoperio.codpaarea', '=',auth()->user()->codarea)
                ->get(),
        'Periodores' => $intervalH,
        'Periodoresm' => $intervalM,
        'Hactual' => $dayy,
        'Hlimit' => $datelim


        ]);
    }
}
```

And my view:

```
@extends('layouts.app')

@section('content')
<div class="container">
    <div class="row justify-content-center">
        <div class="col-md-8">
            <div class="card">
                <div class="card-header"><h4>Fenecer</h4></div>

                <div class="card-body">
                    @if (session('status'))
                        <div class="alert alert-success" role="alert">
                            {{ session('status') }}
                        </div>
                    @endif

                    Welcome {{Auth::user()->name}}, the work for today is:
                    @foreach($Works as $work)

            <li class="list-group-item">
            La informacion por mandar llamada
           <p style="color:red;"> <b>{{$trabajo->descripcion}}</b> </p>
           @if($Hactual<$Hlimit)
            is about to end in
            {{$Periodores}} Hours and
            {{$Periodoresm}} Minutes, the limit is {{$Hlimit}} and the date actual is {{$Hactual}}.
           @elseif($Hactual>$Hlimit)
           <p style="color:red;"> <b> It has passed away please we inform the manager. The work died on {{$Hlimit}} and the actual date is {{$Hactual}} </b> </p>
           @endif
   </li>
@endforeach


                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

As you can see, what I want to do is to display the hours difference ($datelim) in the view in order to know how much each job has left to finish its delivery time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your query and it's below line like this, Because you are  directly passing the `$dateli` which contains the result of query and `strtotime` function expects a string.
I hope it help

```
    $dateli=pamatrixinf::select('pamatrixinf.dateen')
            ->where('pamatrixinf.read_at','=',0,'AND')
            ->where('codpaarea', '=', auth()->user()->codarea)
            ->get()
            ->toArray();
    $datelim= strtotime($dateli[0]['dateen']);
```

Comment: Returning the data I get the dates, but at the time of entering the line "$datelim= strtotime($dateli['dateen']);" I get the error "Undefined index: dateen" to what could it be?